# Error on drush command: In ThemeHandler.php The theme does not exist

Tags: 8, theming, drush

I manage to broke the default theme in development and now could not access the administration interface nor could I change the theme via drush.

The way I broke the default theme is by changing the name of the theme inside yml files and folder and function names without disabling it first. After changing it back to default and flushing the cache this does not fix the error.

No matter what drush command is run the result is the same:

```
In ThemeHandler.php line 491:
The theme my_theme does not exist.
```

Folder is there and all files are there but drush returns always this error.

I try to run:

```
drush config-set system.theme default bartik
```

but the result is the same.

Could I fix this some other way?

Comment: What exactly did you do to break the default theme? Does undoing that not fix it?

Comment: I change the name of files and functions to new ones without disabling the theme I returned all the names to old one but this does not fix it.

Comment: If you undid the changes, rebuilding the cache should fix it

Comment: My first try exactly, but this did not fix it

Comment: I have edit my question with the steps I made before asking it.

Comment: `git reset --hard` to undo file changes, `drush sql-drop` drop current database, `drush sqlc < backup.sql` import backup, done.